# RegEx to find anchor element in HTML page

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-replace

I have a string with mixed content of plain text and html tags. For example:

```
the state of <a href="/wiki/Texas" title="Texas">Texas</a> is a cool place
```

I want to search for this specific string in an HTML page which I get using PHP file_get_contents().

Eventually, I want to replace that string with another string with mixed content.

I tried preg_replace(), however it didn't work.

Is that going to be an easy task with RegEx? Can someone give an example? I'm just starting out with RegEx. If it is not suitable than can you please suggest another solution.

Comment: I dont want to parse the whole HTML page. Looking for specific well known element, which should be an easy task with RegEx. So the question is about how do you construct this specific regular expression

Comment: I thought so but str_replace does not do it for some reason even though the strings are identical. Is it possible that html page adds slashes or some invisible elements that prevent finding the string? Basically I use JS to select portion of an HTML page (text + underlying elements = $string1), then store that in a database. When i do str_replace(string1, string2, $html_domain) nothing happens!

Comment: Bit confusing for me because qus title and desc seems to be different,Tell me what you want to do? Finding anchor tag or some other text in a file?

Comment: Basically, I have $string1 = 'the state of <a href="/wiki/Texas" title="Texas">Texas</a> is a cool place'. When I do str_replace($string1,$string2, $html_page) it doesn't replace it

Comment: I know for sure exactly the same string exist in the page